# I need to define a specific CSS class on the first foreach output in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code to retrieve the results to an image carousel, but I need to add an "active" class on the first div. How do i proceed?

```
$var = explode(',',$rRow["meta_images"]);
foreach($var as $row)
{
  echo '<div class="item">
  <img src="'.$row.'">
  </div>';
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
<div class="item active">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toss in a simple counter. Start at 0 and increment at the end of the `foreach` loop. Check for when the counter is 0. That will match the first time.

```
$var = explode(',',$rRow["meta_images"]);
$i = 0;
foreach($var as $row)
{
  $active = ($i === 0) ? ' active' : '';
  echo '<div class="item'.$active.'">
  <img src="'.$row.'">
  </div>';
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = explode(',',$rRow["meta_images"]);
foreach($var as $key => $row)
{
  if($key == 0) $active = "active";
  else $active = '';
  echo '<div class="'.$active.' item">
  <img src="'.$row.'">
  </div>';
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Right, my bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop -

```
$var = explode(',',$rRow["meta_images"]);
for($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++)
{
  if(0 == $i)
    {
        echo '<div class="active item">';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<div class="item">';
    }
    echo '<img src="'.$var[$i].'"></div>';
}
```